# Converting rows to columns based on Dates in R

Tags: r, tidyr

Suppose I have a data frame that looks like this:

```
car <- c(rep("Acura", 2),rep("Benz", 2), rep("Audi", 2), rep("Toyota", 2), rep("Honda", 2))
date <- rep(c(as.Date("01/01/21"), as.Date("30/01/21")), 5)
mileage <- c(1200, 2400, 1000, 2000, 34000, 34500, 54, 1200, 4000,6000)
avg_speed <- c(24,54,100, 72,65,56,98,NA,55,50)

ex <- data.frame(car, date, mileage, avg_speed)
```

So ex looks like:

```
> ex
      car     date mileage avg_speed
1   Acura  1-01-21    1200        24
2   Acura 30-01-21    2400        54
3    Benz  1-01-21    1000       100
4    Benz 30-01-21    2000        72
5    Audi  1-01-21   34000        65
6    Audi 30-01-21   34500        56
7  Toyota  1-01-21      54        98
8  Toyota 30-01-21    1200        NA
9   Honda  1-01-21    4000        55
10  Honda 30-01-21    6000        50
```

I want my data frame to look like this:

```
       car    mileage_1_01_21    mileage_30_01_21    avg_speed_1_01_21   avg_speed_30_01_21
1    Acura               1200                2400                   24                   54    
2     Benz               1000                2000                  100                   72
3     Audi              34000               34500                   65                   56
4   Toyota                 54                1200                   98                   NA
5    Honda               4000                6000                   55                   50
```

Essentially I want to stratify the columns by each date.
What is the best way to achieve this structure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `dcast` from the `data.table` package:

```
library(data.table)

car <- c(rep("Acura", 2),rep("Benz", 2), rep("Audi", 2), rep("Toyota", 2), rep("Honda", 2))
date <- rep(c(as.Date("01/01/21"), as.Date("30/01/21")), 5)
mileage <- c(1200, 2400, 1000, 2000, 34000, 34500, 54, 1200, 4000,6000)
avg_speed <- c(24,54,100, 72,65,56,98,NA,55,50)

ex <- data.frame(car, date, mileage, avg_speed)

setDT(ex)

ex2 <- dcast(ex, 
             formula = car ~ date,
             value.var = c("mileage", "avg_speed")
)
> ex2
      car mileage_0001-01-21 mileage_0030-01-21 avg_speed_0001-01-21 avg_speed_0030-01-21
1:  Acura               1200               2400                   24                   54
2:   Audi              34000              34500                   65                   56
3:   Benz               1000               2000                  100                   72
4:  Honda               4000               6000                   55                   50
5: Toyota                 54               1200                   98                   NA
```

Answer (score 2):

Try `reshape` like below

```
reshape(
  ex,
  direction = "wide",
  idvar = "car",
  timevar = "date"
)
```

giving

```
     car mileage.0001-01-21 avg_speed.0001-01-21 mileage.0030-01-21
1  Acura               1200                   24               2400
3   Benz               1000                  100               2000
5   Audi              34000                   65              34500
7 Toyota                 54                   98               1200
9  Honda               4000                   55               6000
  avg_speed.0030-01-21
1                   54
3                   72
5                   56
7                   NA
9                   50
```